# Changing django-allauth render_authentication_error behavior

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm a newcomer to the python/Django universe and just started a huge project I'm pretty excited about. I need to have my users login through Facebook and my app has a really specific user flow. I've set up django-allauth and everything works as I needed. I've overriden LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL so that my users land on the page I want when they log in.

BUT. When the user opens Facebook login dialog box and then closes it without logging in, the `authentication_error.html` template gets rendered by `allauth.socialaccount.helpers.render_authentication_error`, and this is not the behaviour I want. I want the user to simply be redirected to the login page.

Yes, I know I could simply override the template by putting it in my `TEMPLATE_DIRS`, but then the url wouldn't be the same.

I've come to the conclusion I needed a **middleware** to intercept the response to the http request.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class Middleware():
    """
    A middleware to override allauth user flow
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.url_to_check = "/accounts/facebook/login/token/"

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        """
        In case of failed faceboook login
        """
        if request.path == self.url_to_check and\
                not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return redirect('/')

        return response
```

But I'm not sure about the efficiency of my solution nor the pythonesquitude (I juste came up with that word) of it. Is there anything else I could do to change that default django-allauth behavior without using a middleware or a signal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use a middleware and redirect to home url in case a GET request is made on a URL of the form `^/accounts/.*$`

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
import re


class AllauthOverrideMiddleware():
    """
    A middleware to implement a custom user flow
    """
    def __init__(self):
        # allauth urls
        self.url_social = re.compile("^/accounts/.*$")

    def process_request(self, request):

        # WE CAN ONLY POST TO ALLAUTH URLS
        if request.method == "GET" and\
           self.url_social.match(request.path):
            return redirect("/")
```

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, I know I could simply override the template by putting it in my TEMPLATE_DIRS, but then the url wouldn't be the same.

Overriding a template won't change the URL. In your overridden template, you could do a [client-side redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) to whatever URL you prefer.

Comment: What I meant is the URL wouldn't be the same as the root url where I want to redirect on login error. Anyway, I've chose to simply use a middleware and redirect GET requests to /accounts/* to root url

Comment: Cool, glad you found a solution.